# How to root my android phone?

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-3

How can I **root** my *android* phone ...

Please provide answer in easy steps ...

I am using ...

- Samsung I9300 Galaxy S III
- Android OS v4.0.4 (Ice Cream Sandwich)

If anyone know then share

Comment: please give more details like which S 3 variant you are using?

Comment: Exactly in the same name of your question there is another [question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device). Have you seen whether your device is listed there?

Comment: [Root Samsung Galaxy S3](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26879/16575) should answer your question. Provides a solution for the i9300.

Comment: If I google "root samsung galaxy s3", all the results state the root procedure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1**
Power off your Galaxy S3.  Then hold down Volume Down, Center Home, and Power buttons together until you see the warning screen.

**Step 2**
Hit Volume Up button to enter Download ODIN mode and connect a microUSB cable from your Galaxy S3 to your computer.

**Step 3**
Next, download [GalaxyS3RootNew.zip](http://downloadandroidrom.com/file/GalaxyS3/rooting/GalaxyS3RootNew.zip), unzip the files and run odin3v1.85.exe by double-clicking on the file.

**Step 4**
When ODIN program opens, you should find a highlighted yellow box with a random COM number.  If you don’t see this, download and install [Samsung USB drivers](http://stockroms.net/file/Drivers/Samsung/SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones.exe)

**Step 5**
DO NOT TOUCH ANYTHING ELSE, hit “PDA” button and select the file CF-Root-SGS3-v6.4.tar.

**Step 6**
Hit “Start” button.  This will install ClockworkMod Recovery on your Galaxy S3 i9300.   If you get stuck on this step, just try a different USB port.

**Step 7**
Once ODIN is done flashing, you will see “PASS!” in green highlighted box.

**Step 8**
Your Galaxy S3 will reboot once into CWM Recovery and automatically install root and Superuser app.

**Step 9**
Once your phone reboots, you will find an app called “SuperSU”, this is your superuser app.

**Step 10**
Download and install Titanium Backup app from Play Store to verify you have root, a Superuser request window should pop up.

That’s it!  This should take you less than 5 minutes to do and does not affect your phone in any way but give you Superuser, root, and custom ClockworkMod Recovery.

**You can find video and More details [here](http://galaxys3root.com/galaxy-s3-root/how-to-root-galaxy-s3-jelly-bean-or-ics/)**
**NOTE**: I'm not resposible for any of your activities. **Do it on your own RISK**.

Comment: _@MattLin_ I will try this, **Thank you** dear :)