# How to root Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

Does anybody know how to root the Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini?

- Model Number : GT-I8190
- Android Version : 4.1.2

Comment: You might like to start by reading the [tag wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info) for [tag:rooting].

Comment: And if the hardware is not that different, steps for the [Galaxy S3](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/26880/16575) might apply for the mini as well.

Comment: Usually Faramaroot app works for root , incase if it is not working that you should try by connecting you mobile to pc with usb debugging and use Root Genius software and try root. Download from here -  http://www.shuame.com/en/root/

Answer (score 1):

You can root your Galaxy S3 Mini without computer without PC.

1. Go to Settings>Security>Check Allow Unknown resources.
2. Download **Root Master 2.0 apk** from [here](http://d-h.st/Ou9).
3. Install it as normal apk. Open the app and click **root**.
4. Now the phone will restart and you'll see **Kinguser** in your app
   drawer.
5. To Verify Root, Download **Root Checker Basic** from Playstore.

Regards,

Phantasam

Comment: Did not work for me

Comment: Strange. Well you can try flashing the cf root file via Odin.

Answer (score 0):

I used towelroot

https://towelroot.com/

to root a GS3 Mini (another variant though) successfully. I guess its worth a try!

Comment: Thank you for suggesting an answer (though link-only it is). However, there is not much in this answer other than the name of the app (already in the tag-wiki suggested in a comment under the question). Please make this answer  useful by adding instructions(*know-how*).

Comment: link says - "Your connection is not private".

Comment: Dear, Firelord. If someone succeeded using this resource, than the answer is valid. Now, let's see how many upvotes it will get.