# SuperSU Errors when rooting Galaxy S3

Tags: rooting

I recently managed to root my Samsung Galaxy S3 by following [this previous answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26879/how-can-i-root-my-samsung-galaxy-s3-should-i-defer-the-system-update).

However when running the SuperSU app that was automatically loaded after rooting, I get the message:

> The su binary needs to be updated. continue?

Then when I click OK, it gives the error:

> Installation failed!

I wondered if the version of the SuperSU app installed by [the rooting software](http://downloadandroidrom.com/file/GalaxyS3/rooting/GalaxyS3Root.zip) on my PC was old, so I did this:

1. Opened SuperSU app
2. Went to `Settings > Reinstall` [cleanup for reinstallation from Google Play]
3. Went to Google Play, then  installed [this version of the SuperSU app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu).
4. But running the new version then gave the same error message.

I'm not sure step 2 worked because it says: "If cleanup succeeds, this app will close automatically in a few seconds. Afterwards, please reinstall SuperSU from Google Play. Are you sure you want to continue?" But then it never closes.

I know the phone had root because I downloaded a root testing app and it confirmed it.

**What am I doing wrong?**

I tried a number of links ([like this one](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1538053&page=68)) and couldn't find anything else that made sense to me. Please could someone suggest what I should be doing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I simply had to download a more up-to-date file (which included the Odin executable which runs on the PC, and the .tar that it uploads to the phone) from [here](http://autoroot.chainfire.eu/), using the table to look up the appropriate file for my device.

For my Samsung Galaxy S3 (GT-i9300) The file was `CF-Auto-Root-m0-m0xx-gti9300.zip` available from [here](http://download.chainfire.eu/229/CF-Root/CF-Auto-Root/CF-Auto-Root-m0-m0xx-gti9300.zip).