# SuperSU app gives "No SU binary installed" error

Tags: rooting, root-access, supersu

I have a *(partially)* rooted Samsung Note 2. I can't access the SuperSU app.
Whenever I try to open it, I get the error *No Su binary installed* and it doesn't install it.
I used Root Checker App too and it says the phone is not rooted completely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Galaxy S3 , Supersu reports no SU binary installed](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/92791/galaxy-s3-supersu-reports-no-su-binary-installed)

Comment: Did you actually flash the latest SuperSU zip with custom recovery? The way you should do it is flash custom recovery, flash the zip, enter the app, and then UPDATE through play store, not install through play store

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you can do here try to uninstall all the applications that are related to super user. first install" [System app remover](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jumobile.manager.systemapp) and uninstall the applications restart your phone and install root checker-supersu. 
Ping me in if you find any more issues.